# Mascaramento de domínio com Tomcat e SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, redirecionamento-de-url

estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web usando SpringBoot, e outras tecnologias. Esta aplicação será unica, ou seja, uma aplicação deve atender vários usuários (clientes).

Cada usuário terá uma página, que é composta da seguinte forma: `www.meusite.com.br/joao_da_silva`

O dominio do site pode ser: *meusite.com.br* e o que está depois da barra, é o nome de usuário dele (no caso *joao_da_silva*).

Até ai tudo bem, desenvolvi a aplicação, e está funcionando bem. Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

**Tem como o cliente ter um domínio 'x' (exemplo: www.joaodasilva.com.br) e redirecionar para www.meusite.com.br/joao_da_silva sem alterar a URL?**

Eu vi que a goDaddy tem uma funcionalidade de mascaramento, porém fica um HTML com iframe, alem de ficar lento, perde toda a responsividade do site, pois o mascaramento da goDaddy usa HTML 4. Isso não me serve, por que já testei.

Como eu uso servidor tomcat para outras aplicações que tenho, já usei uma espécie de virtual host, alterando o arquivo server.xml e adicionado uma tag Host, consigo apontar um domínio, para uma pasta (aplicação), porém isso não me resolve (ou configurei errado), pois eu preciso apontar vários dominios de cliente para a mesma aplicação, alterando apenas o endpoint (que é o nome do cliente), se eu coloco 2 host para a mesma aplicação o tomcat entra em loop, e não para de fazer deploy. 
Talvez eu tenha feito a configuração de forma errada, mas até agora não achei nenhuma solução.

O que mudei no server.xml está assim:

```
<Host name="joaodasilva.com.br" appBase="MEUAPP" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true">
       <Alias>www.joaodasilva.com.br</Alias>
        <Context path="" docBase="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/MEUAPP/joao_da_silva" debug="0"/>
</Host>
<Host name="mariapaula.com" appBase="MEUAPP" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true">
        <Alias>www.mariapaula.com</Alias>
        <Context path="" docBase="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/MEUAPP/maria_de_paula" debug="0"/>
</Host>
```

O que quero fazer, é quando acessar o dominio: www.joaodasilva.com.br apontar para www.meusite.com.br/joao_da_silva (site: meusite.com.br endpoint: joao_da_silva) sem alterar a URL.

Comment: Dá uma olhada [nesse material aqui](http://blog.alura.com.br/como-configurar-virtual-hosts-no-apache/), pode lhe dar um norte sobre o problema.

Comment: Pois é, mas eu uso tomcat, sabe se teria alguma forma de redirecionar um domínio para um contexto da minha aplicação?